# sendbird push notification not received if app is in foreground

Tags: android, sendbird

I am having a problem while I am open app on another screen the push notification of sendbird is not sent , I need to update the message count of my messages in sendbird , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check point 4 in this [link](https://help.sendbird.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002331048-Why-am-I-not-receiving-push-notifications-) answer in sendBird help center the question **Why am I not receiving push notifications?**
.

It says :

> 4. A user must be offline - they must be disconnected from ALL devices.

So when the app in the foreground that mean the sendBird user is online and the way they implement it that they don't send notification for the online users which is disappointing to know.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Nawaf. I should add if it works for anyone:

Keep unread message count as 1 or coloured dot on your notification badge inside app, when you get SendBird notification on your launcher activity intent. Hide the dot when user clicks the badge.